# Mouse position on extended displays

Tags: c#, .net, mouse, multiple-monitors

I could not find anything on this particular problem, so here it goes!

I am interested in changing the position of the mouse cursor programmatically.

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(x, y);
```

works as expected using a single monitor. However, when I plug in a second one and choose to extend the desktop, changing the cursor's coordinates only works relative to the main screen.

So, does anyone know how to tell the cursor that I want to move to a different screen?

Comment: you could try using the Screen.AllScreens array

Comment: That's an interesting method, but I don't see anything in the Screen class that would help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the width and height of your required screen and move the cursor relative to it

```
int width=Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Width;
int height=Screen.AllScreens[1].Bounds.Height;
Cursor.Position=new Point(width-x,height-y);
```

Comment: It's not completely correct. I had to get the X and Y coordinates of Bounds, but it did help me solve the problem. I did not realize another monitor simply extends the coordinate system, in my case into negative values on the X axis.